# How to corrupt an ext3 partition so that it will undergo fsck to fix automatically at boot?

Tags: linux, ext3, fsck

I'm looking for a way to corrupt an ext3 partition safely, so that it can be recovered by fsck on next boot, for testing purposes. Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to force a fsck on reboot?  There are safer, easier and better ways to do that.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for force fsck using "touch /forcefsck" or something. I just want to see how it behaves when the file system is actually corrupt. And I don't worry about data loss in test environment. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to emphasize the "seek=10000" that @MadHatter just wrote, please don't omit it from your testing or you're screwed without a full disk backup. You should probably add this as an answer?

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer and deleted it as a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dd to write data from `/dev/zero` on top of the raw device.  Start with a few bytes, `e2fsck -p`, repeat, increasing the count until you trash something expensive.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=10 of=/dev/sda1 seek=10000
```

You increase `count=` to write more.  The `seek=` is designed to pass over the first 10k of /dev/sda1 so you don't trash the superblock or any of the vital structures at the top of the filesystem.  There's nothing wrong with trashing the superblock (given that this is test data), but fsck won't be able to autorecover from loss of the superblock so you'll have to manually point it to a backup superblock.  You specifically ask about what the reboot fsck can recover from, so you should know that the `-p` flag puts fsck into the boot-time "fix what you can safely fix" mode.

If you do this on a data partition, you can avoid the reboot cost, and just keep the trash-fsck cycle going.

Answer (score 3):

You could overwrite the first superblock, for ext3 it would be

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=4096 seek=0 of=/dev/<filesystem to corrupt>
```

That's a fun thing to recover from. You also don't need to reboot just use fsck interactively.